# How to use drupal db connection in external php files as well as $base_url path

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 to build a website. we have some external core PHP files, where we need Drupal `$base_url` and database connection.

Comment: You need to include drupal bootstrap file in your external files. [More details](https://drupal.org/node/166409).

Comment: Ok and for $base_url ?